# Can I assume boto3 'describe_instance_status response' will never be partial? more specifically regarding 'InstanceStatus' attribute

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, boto3

I couldn't find in this [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_instance_status) or any where else an answer for the question whether I can assume boto3 ec2 client `describe_instance_status` query response will never be partial?

To be more specific here is a snippet from a typical `describe_instance_status` response of the `InstanceStatus` attribute when the instance status check failed:

```
"InstanceStatus": {
    "Details": [
        {
            "ImpairedSince": datetime(2015, 1, 1),
            "Name": "reachability",
            "Status": "failed",
        }
    ],
    "Status": "impaired",
}
```

The instance status status is `impaired` so the question is, can I assume `ImpairedSince` will always be given in this case or maybe sometimes this data will be missing from the response though the status is `impaired`. 
And if it can be missing, what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html) said:

> Status checks are performed every minute, returning a pass or a fail status. If all checks pass, the overall status of the instance is OK. **If one or more checks fail, the overall status is `impaired`.** Status checks are built into Amazon EC2, so they cannot be disabled or deleted.

And another [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_InstanceStatusDetails.html):

> `impairedSince`: **The time when a status check failed.** For an instance that was launched and impaired, this is the time when the instance was launched.

Conclusion: The `ImpairedSince` key will only be given in the `InstanceStatusDetails` object where the `Status` is `failed`. If at least one status check is failed, the `Status` of the overall `InstanceStatusSummary` object will be `impaired`.

Comment: @shiraev yes, it will.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but thought what you said is true it doesn't really answering my question.
I understand that the ImpairedSince key will only be given in the InstanceStatusDetails object when the Status is failed, however will it *always* appear? can I count on this object to always have ImpairedSince attribute? that's another question and this is what I am trying to figure out here.

Comment: @shiraev I've already explained in my answer. `impairedSince: The time when a status check failed.`

Comment: when I said 'however will it *always* appear?' I meant *always when status is impaired*.
In other words, can I ever get this response for some reason?

`"InstanceStatus": {
    "Details": [
        {
            "Name": "reachability",
            "Status": "failed",
        }
    ],
    "Status": "impaired",
}`